# Internet connection drastically different for users

Tags: networking, fedora, internet

I am using Fedora 16, I know it's been EOL-ed but I've been too lazy to update and reinstall something new.  Mostly, it works fine except that my main user's internet connection is really crappy and getting dropped all the time under the main admin user.  When my mom visited a few months back, I created a separate user for her.  When I log in as her, the connection is super fast.  Like a different laptop.

Which directories should I look for possible filled up space to clean up?  I went under `/home/username` but didn't find anything there.  What could be possible other reasons why connectivity speed differs drastically between users?  Clearing history doesn't do much.

Comment: How are you testing?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new, clean Firefox profile in your account?